# ListView personalizado

Tags: android

Estou tentando fazer um ListView Personalizado. Eu tenho meu XLM

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewCliente"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
    tools:listitem="@layout/row_cliente"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Percebam que ali eu coloque um tools: e apontei para outro XML para pegar o estilo personalizado.

Na aba design ele mostra o listview correto e já personalizado. Mas quando instalo no meu celular ou no emulador ele mostra a lista padrão.

Alguém já passou por isso? Ja tentei desinstalar e instalar novamente, mas nada.

Comment: Troca o listitem por isso aqui e vê se funciona: `tools:listitem="@layout/sample_list_item"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para usar um layout personalizado na ListView, você tem que definir um arquivo XML de layout representando uma linha da ListView e escrever um Adapter personalizado para sua lista que vai dizer como colocar cada dado nas views desse XML. Por fim, na MainActivity, você vai criar um Array de Objetos com os dados que você quer mostrar na ListView e associar esse Adapter à ListView passando como parâmetros para o mesmo o Array e o id do XML.

Um exemplo: http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter